# Replacing SVG block with js

Tags: jquery, image, svg, responsive-design

I have two `SVG` image files. Other is supposed to use on desktop sizes and another on mobile sizes. But how can I change between the files? I can't use just simply `img` tag because I have link inside `svg`. Current implemention is following..

In my template:

```
<?php include("img/content/myimage_mobile.svg"); ?>
```

Now this works perfectly fine on mobile. The link etc. works nicely. But when come to desktop size, how can I change that file to `myimage.svg`? With `JS` somehow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haha, sorry for this. This actually was stupid. Of course I just wrap those SVGs into two divs and then with CSS & media queries show those divs on right moments :D